# How to automate migrating data from multiple access database into a single sql server database?

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure

I have a task to migrate data from multiple access database to a sql server database.

- My initial approach was to create a web page to allow the user to
  upload mdb file.
- Once the upload completes, a message will sent to
  the azure storage queue.
- A background processor listens to the queue will process the uploaded mdb file to collect all the data from the mdb file and import to the SQL server database.

The above is my approach, appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Approach seems good to me, few addition:

- My initial approach was to create a web page to allow the user to upload mdb file.

  Seems Fine
- Once the upload completes, a message will sent to the azure storage queue.

  Seems Fine, You can use Service bus queue for the same.
- A background processor listens to the queue will process the uploaded mdb file to collect all the data from the mdb file and import to the SQL server database.

  You can use Azure function with Service bus queue and write the required code to import it in SQL.

Alternatively you can also explore Azure data factory for this requirement, You can create a pipeline which will do all task for you.